# Make `li` Class active capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

New to Capybara and Rspec.

I want to make an `li` class active in my code but having issues. I wrote this line of code that finds the li element that I need and i am trying to make it active but having some errors.

This is the code i have written so far

```
find("ul.nav.nav-tabs  li.col-sm-4.col-md-4", :text=> 'TOOLS').('li.active')
```

Does anyone have any solution on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOlved it guys. i had to make sure i was referencing the  tag which includes the link

```
**find("ul.nav.nav-tabs  li.col-sm-4.col-md-4 a", :text=> 'TOOLS').click**
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't make it active on your own, This is a scenario imagine it in reality, Are you doing some action on something that triggers the active class?